# Can all small EBNF rules in Python be composed into a larger correct one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, ebnf

I found this rule  [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists),i just didn't figure out how `"*" or_expr` is equivalent as `starred_item` .If there is nothing wrong, what is it the problem that caused my code `a = 8;b = 2; *(a >> b), = (1,2,3)` to raise a exception,which said "SyntaxError: can't assign to operator"?

Comment: What would you even want to happen with this statement?

Comment: That code doesn't make sense, so it's perfectly understandable that it raises `SyntaxError`. OTOH, `*a, = 1, 2, 3` is valid (in recent versions of Python).

Comment: I am studying the syntax of Python expression.I derived the rule` *(identifier   ">>"  identifier)` from the specificated rules, which is classified as `starred_expression`.A tuple or list can appear at the left hand side of the simple assignment, so can ` *(identifier   ">>"  identifier),` .but i didn't get the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atribution in Python - which happens with the assignment operator `=` or one of the augmented operators (`+=`, `-=`, ...) is actually a statement, and can't be used as part of a normal expression as in C-syntax derived Languages.

The left part of an assignment must make sense as a variable name (or a sequence of names).

The expression you are trying to use there `*a >> b, = (1,2,3)` (to which I admit I can't understand what you wanted to achieve) is equivalent to a sequence were the first (and only) element is `*a >> b` - that is nor a valid name in Python - therefore your error.

The "*a" in assignemnts mean that any lenght that "is left of" after attribution to other parts of the sequence of names are assigned to the starred name:

```
In [3]: *a, b = (1, 2, 3)

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [1, 2]

In [5]: b
Out[5]: 3
```

And that is deterministic and works whenever a * appears:

```
In [6]: a, b, *c, d = range(10)

In [7]: [a, b, c, d]
Out[7]: [0, 1, [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 9]
```

And of course, if one tries to use two stars, that results in an error due to the ambiguity:

```
In [8]: *a, *b, c = range(5)
  File "<ipython-input-8-e75ad61b842a>", line 1
    *a, *b, c = range(5)
                        ^
SyntaxError: two starred expressions in assignment
```

Again, note that in no way an arbitrary expression is allowed on the left side of an attribution operator.

On non-assignemnt expressions, the * operator can be used to expand in place an iterable. Up to Python 3.5, that was only possible on function calls - now it is possible anywhere were a sequence of literals is expected:

```
In [9]: a = 0, *range(10, 12), 2

In [10]: a
Out[10]: (0, 10, 11, 2)
```

Comment: I knew this conclusion ,which was introduced by [PEP-3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

Comment: I find the EBNF rule of [assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) ,which explained  my situation and comfirmed your answer.